# Getting Bearer token from NextAuth session

Tags: reactjs, next-auth, bearer-token

I have following code defined for callbacks in [...nextauth].js

```
callbacks: {
async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
  if (account) {
    token.accessToken = account.accessToken;
    token.id = profile.id;
  }
  return token;
},
async session({ session, token, user }) {
  session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
  session.user.id = token.id;

  return session;
  },
},
```

Then from documents I read this to get access token

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt"

const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // if using `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` env variable, we detect it, and you won't actually need to `secret`
  // const token = await getToken({ req })
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret })
  console.log("JSON Web Token", token)
  res.end()
}
```

What I want to do is to use this token to access an API, so when I make a fetch request I would like to attach this token onto it. Problem is that I do not understand what is this "handler" function and how it is invoked ? Where are those req and response coming from?

When I want to use getToken() it requires req as a parameter, where do I get it?

Probably something really simple but I'm just unaware whats going on.